# Problem while building webkitestcases.apk for CTS

Tags: android, android-source, cts

I am trying to build the webkittestcases.apk for CTS execution but while building the apk i am getting follwing error

```
out/build-aosp_arm-cts_tests_tests_webkit_Android.mk.ninja is missing, regenerating...
PRODUCT_COPY_FILES device/.../..:root/stab ignored.
PRODUCT_COPY_FILES device/..../.early:root/stab.early ignored.
device/qcom/...../vendor_bootjars.mk:7: error: cannot assign to readonly variable: PRODUCT_BOOT_JARS
ckati failed with: exit status 1
```

My AOSP android version is 8.1

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you try to assign something to `PRODUCT_BOOT_JARS` at a late stage of the make process. `PRODUCT_BOOT_JARS` becomes `readonly` after [build/make/core/product.mk](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/build/+/refs/heads/oreo-release/core/product.mk#301) is included.

You need to move assignments to `PRODUCT_BOOT_JARS` (or the include of `vendor_bootjars.mk`) to your `device/qcom/.../<product>.mk` or `device/qcom/.../AndroidProducts.mk`.

See https://source.android.com/setup/develop/new-device#makefiles

Comment: Hi @Simpl,
I am new to this could you please elaborate what you mean by " You need to move assignments to PRODUCT_BOOT_JARS " and " (or the include of vendor_bootjars.mk) to your device/qcom/.../<product>.mk or device/qcom/.../AndroidProducts.mk "

Comment: I cannot tell where exactly vendor_bootjars.mk is included from your question. I assume it is added in `BoardConfig.mk`?